# How to display the value of activation?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, tensorflow, activation-function

I have built my network and would like to see how the activation of a particular layer change after each epoch of training. For example, as code shown below, I want to see the activation values of "act_layer_1". What should I do so that I can see the activation values? Thanks in advance!

```
W1 = tf.get_variable('W1', [n_input,n_hidden_1], initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(seed = 1))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[n_hidden_1], dtype=tf.float32), trainable=True, name='b1'),
act_layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(hidden_layer(x_image, W1) + b1)
drop_layer_1 = tf.nn.dropout(act_layer_1, keep_prob)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you have not made it clear in your code snippet but the `activation` output could be inside or outside a function:

- Outside Function : Just run

```
a = sess.run(act_layer_1)
print(a)
```

- Inside Function: You have to return the value of this `activation` bunched with other values you need to print and then again use `sess.run()` to get all the values and print the index which contains your value.

A longer but better in debugging would be to use tf.InteractiveSession(). More details can be found here:

[How to print the value of a Tensor object in TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33633370/how-to-print-the-value-of-a-tensor-object-in-tensorflow)

Comment: I tried this and it does work.

Comment: @Joshua well then you can accept my answer by clicking on the tick :)

Comment: Sorry, typo. It "doesn't" work out.

Comment: @Joshua it should work...can you provide the full code?

Comment: Sure. By emailing you?

Comment: @Joshua no here in this question..If it's confidential you need work it out yourself by checking the link I provided

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81742/discussion-between-joshua-and-duttaa).